# Mixin using LESS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

I'm reading the LESS official documentation (version 1.5) but I cannot understand how to import a reference to another CSS in order to use its content in my own file. For example:

mystyle.less

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap.min.css";
.mylabel {
    .label-success;
}
```

It shows this error: `NameError: .label-success is undefined`

Perhaps I misunderstand the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `reference` with other LESS files. You cannot mix and match LESS and CSS files with that method.

If you need to use the mixins from Bootstrap, grab the Bootstrap LESS files.

**Update:**
You can also specify the reference type, which should work for what you need:

```
@import (reference, less) "bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: Actually you can use it with CSS too, I have just tried it with `@import (reference, less) "bootstrap.min.css";` and it works (in 1.5.1 at least).

Comment: Yes, but that actually references the file into memory (as parsed LESS code) and then renders the used mixins only. I've updated my answer to include the `reference, less` caveat.

Comment: Not quite. Imported CSS files without the `reference, less` flag are not passed through the parser (thus not loaded into memory). They are simply added to the generated `<style>` tag (or file) as an `@import` rule.

Comment: (I'm sorry, I deleted my prev. comment before I saw your reply to it). Either way, of course it has to parse it since otherwise it just cannot know of any `.label-success` inside.

Comment: No. If you use a regular `@import` inside of your LESS file, no attempt is made to parse the contents. The fact that the browser knows how to style `.label-success` is due to traditional CSS parsing, NOT LESS parsing. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: I don't confuse them of course. I mean "LESS has to parse it since otherwise it just cannot know of any .label-success inside". E.g. in other words, "loading css file into memory" for mixin reuse cannot be treated as disadvantage just because it is the only way to do it.

Comment: I didn't say it was a disadvantage... My point regarding the comment was that my answer is still valid, you can't use mixins from raw CSS files ;)