# NameError: variable @screen-sm-min is undefined

Tags: css, less

I've a file name `base.less` and  another file `private.less` which imports `base.less`.
In `base.less` I have this code

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {

}
```

when I try to compile with `lessc base.less private.css` I get this error

```
NameError: variable @screen-sm-min is undefined in base.less
```

It's not my code and I'm new on less,somebody knows what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Bootstrap styles in a LESS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20767152/how-can-i-use-bootstrap-styles-in-a-less-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the variable `@screen-sm-min` to your `base.less` like this `@screen-sm-min: 375px;` **before** you use that variable somewhere. Ideally you create a file called `vars.less` and put all your variables in there and include that in your `base.less` file.

**vars.less**

```
@screen-sm-min: 375px;
@default-background-color: #fff;
@my-special-border-color: red;
```

Now you can use `@screen-sm-min` anywhere in your css. Also, check out http://lesscss.org/#variables

Comment: Just a minor remark - in Less [you don't have](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-evaluation) to declare a variable *before* it's used.